# How to compare two project files in DbSchema

Tags: database, database-design, db-schema

I am using DbSchema (https://dbschema.com/) and I can't find a way to compare two different versions of the same project file and see the changes. Can I compare them the same way as I compare the project file with the database?

Answer (score 0):

Look in 'Schema' menu. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iz3M6.png)

This can be automated with Groovy scripts, so you can generate migration scripts between two versions of the same schema on the fly. [Details here](https://dbschema.com/documentation/automation-api.html)